# In Java 8, why is the default capacity of ArrayList now zero?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

As I recall, before Java 8, the default capacity of `ArrayList` was 10.

Surprisingly, the comment on the default (void) constructor still says: `Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.`

From `ArrayList.java`:

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for default sized empty instances. We
 * distinguish this from EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA to know how much to inflate when
 * first element is added.
 */
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};

...

/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Technically, it's `10`, not zero, if you admit for a lazy initialisation of the backing array. See:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}

private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    if (elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
    }

    ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
}
```

where

```
/**
 * Default initial capacity.
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
```

What you're referring to is just the zero-sized initial array object that is shared among all initially empty `ArrayList` objects. I.e. the capacity of `10` is guaranteed *lazily*, an optimisation that is present also in Java 7.

Admittedly, the constructor contract is not entirely accurate. Perhaps this is the source of confusion here.

#### Background

Here's an E-Mail by Mike Duigou

> I have posted an updated version of the empty ArrayList and HashMap patch.
>
> http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mduigou/JDK-7143928/1/webrev/
>
> This revised implementation introduces *no new fields* to either class. For ArrayList the lazy allocation of the backing array occurs only if the list is created at default size. According to our performance analysis team, approximately 85% of ArrayList instances are created at default size so this optimization will be valid for an overwhelming majority of cases.
>
> For HashMap, creative use is made of the threshold field to track the requested initial size until the bucket array is needed. On the read side the empty map case is tested with isEmpty(). On the write size a comparison of (table == EMPTY_TABLE) is used to detect the need to inflate the bucket array. In readObject there's a little more work to try to choose an efficient initial capacity.
>
> *From: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-April/015585.html*

Comment: Interesting: So the default capacity memory allocation contract has changed: Eager became lazy.

Comment: It is odd that the initially empty array list claims a capacity of 10 before it has any capacity at all. What is the point of reporting your capacity if it doesn't tell you how many elements it has already made space for?

Comment: According to http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7143928 it leads to reduce heap usage and improved response times (the numbers for two appications are shown)

Comment: @khelwood: ArrayList doesn't really "report" its capacity, other than via this Javadoc: there's no `getCapacity()` method, or anything like that. (That said, something like `ensureCapacity(7)` is a no-op for a default-initialized ArrayList, so I guess we really are supposed to act as though its initial capacity were truly 10 . . .)

Comment: Nice digging. The default initial capacity is indeed not zero, but 10, with the default case being lazily allocated as a special case. You can observe this if you repeatedly add elements to an `ArrayList` created with the no-arg constructor vs passing zero to the `int` constructor, and if you look at the internal array size reflectively or in a debugger. In the default case the array jumps from length 0 to 10, then to 15, 22, following the 1.5x growth rate. Passing zero as the initial capacity results in growth from 0 to 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 19....

Comment: It isn't stated anywhere in the bug reports that I can see, but the reason for this change isn't so much about performance as memory consumption. Heap profiles of real applications showed that it was very common (perhaps absurdly common) for applications to allocate `ArrayList` instances of the default size and then **never** add any elements. Lazily allocating the backing array in this case saved significant amounts of heap. When code passed an explicit initial capacity, it usually was going to add around that number of elements, so lazy allocation didn't help those cases.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: we can see it also the other way round. In our applications we *did* care and initialize a lot of `List` variables with `Collections.emptyList()` and replace it with an `ArrayList` when we are going to actually add elements which implies having tons of conditional code checking for empty list before any adding of elements. With the new `ArrayList` implementation, we can just use `ArrayList` and get rid of our conditional code.

Comment: @StuartMarks: Thanks a lot for the explanation. This would almost qualify as an answer on its own :)

Comment: I am Mike Duigou, author of the change and the quoted email and I approve this message.  As Stuart says the motivation was primarily about space saving rather than performance though there is also a slight performance benefit due to frequently avoiding creation of the backing array.

Comment: @Holger `@Deprecated emptyList`? ;-)

Comment: @assylias: ;^) no, it still has its place as a singleton `emptyList()` still consumes less memory than several empty `ArrayList` instances. It’s just less important now and thus not needed at *every* place, especially not at places with a higher likelihood of adding elements at a later time. Also keep in mind that you sometimes *want* an immutable empty list and then `emptyList()` is the way to go.

Comment: Does it mean from @LukasEder 's answer that, initially the size is zero, but as soon as we add first element, initialCapacity becomes 10?

Comment: @NisargPatil: Yes

Comment: @StuartMarks but why make this distinction between `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` and `DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` and inflate at a different pace for different constructors?

Comment: @Eugene Prior to this change `new ArrayList<>()` and `new ArrayList<>(0)` would have different growth sequences. The empty sentinel arrays were added so that allocation could be done lazily while preserving the growth sequences.

Comment: @StuartMarks Ive posted a question about this... Holger seems to nailed it.

Answer (score 30):

In java 8 default capacity of ArrayList is 0 until we add at least one object into the ArrayList object (You can call it lazy initialization).

Now question is why this change has been done in JAVA 8?

Answer is to save memory consumption. Millions of array list objects are created in real time java applications. Default size of 10 objects means that we allocate 10 pointers (40 or 80 bytes) for underlying array at creation and fill them in with nulls.
An empty array (filled with nulls) occupy lot of memory .

Lazy initialization postpones this memory consumption till moment you will actually use the array list.

Please see below code for help.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();          //Size:  0, Capacity:  0
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(5);         //Size:  0, Capacity:  5
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(5)); //Size:  0, Capacity:  0
al.add( "shailesh" );                    //Size:  1, Capacity: 10

public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        getCapacity( al );
        al.add( "shailesh" );
        getCapacity( al );
    }

    static void getCapacity( ArrayList<?> l )
        throws Exception
    {
        Field dataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField( "elementData" );
        dataField.setAccessible( true );
        System.out.format( "Size: %2d, Capacity: %2d%n", l.size(), ( (Object[]) dataField.get( l ) ).length );
}

Response: - 
Size:  0, Capacity:  0
Size:  1, Capacity: 10
```

Article [Default capacity of ArrayList in Java 8](https://programingsoeasy.blogspot.in/2018/05/in-java-8-why-is-default-capacity-of.html) explains it in details.

Answer (score 7):

If the very first operation that is done with an ArrayList is to pass `addAll` a collection which has more than ten elements, then any effort put into creating an initial ten-element array to hold the ArrayList's contents would be thrown out the window.  Whenever something is added to an ArrayList it's necessary to test whether the size of the resulting list will exceed the size of the backing store; allowing the initial backing store to have size zero rather than ten will cause this test to fail one extra time in the lifetime of a list whose first operation is an "add" which would require creating the initial ten-item array, but that cost is less than the cost of creating a ten-item array that never ends up getting used.

That having been said, it might have been possible to improve performance further in some contexts if there were a overload of "addAll" which specified how many items (if any) would likely be added to the list after the present one, and which could use that to influence its allocation behavior.  In some cases code which adds the last few items to a list will have a pretty good idea that the list is never going to need any space beyond that.  There are many situations where a list will get populated once and never modified after that.  If at the point code knows that the ultimate size of a list will be 170 elements, it has 150 elements and a backing store of size 160, growing the backing store to size 320 will be unhelpful and leaving it at size 320 or trimming it to 170 will be less efficient than simply having the next allocation grow it to 170.

Comment: Very good points about `addAll()`.  That is yet another opportunity for improving efficiency around the first malloc.

Comment: @kevinarpe: I wish Java's library had engineered in some more ways for programs to indicate how things were likely to be used.  The old style of substring, for example, was lousy for some uses cases, but excellent for others.  Had there been separate functions for "substring which is likely to outlast the original" and "substring which is unlikely to outlast the original", and code used the right one 90% of the time, I would think those could have greatly outperformed either the old or new string implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The question is 'why?'.

Memory profiling inspections (for example (https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/inspections_mem.jsp#sparse_arrays) shows that empty (filled with nulls) arrays occupy tons of memory .

Default size of 10 objects means that we allocate 10 pointers (40 or 80 bytes) for underlying array at creation and fill them in with nulls. Real java applications create millions of array lists.

The introduced modification removes^W postpone this memory consumption till moment you will actually use the array list.

Comment: Please correct "consume" with "waste". The link you provide does not imply they start gobbling up memory everywhere, just that arrays with null elements waste the memory that is allocated for them, disproportionately. "Consume" implies they magically use memory beyond their allocation, which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

After above question I gone through ArrayList Document of Java 8. I found the default size is still 10 only.

[image: Please see below]

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList default size in JAVA 8 is stil 10. The only change made in JAVA 8 is that if a coder adds elements less than 10 then the remaining arraylist blank places are not specified to null. Saying so because I have myself gone through this situation and eclipse made me look into this change of JAVA 8.

You can justify this change by looking at below screenshot. In it you can see that ArrayList size is specified as 10 in Object[10] but the number of elements displayed are only 7. Rest null value elements are not displayed here. In JAVA 7 below screenshot is same with just a single change which is that the null value elements are also displayed for which the coder needs to write code for handling null values if he is iterating complete array list while in JAVA 8 this burden is removed from the head of coder/developer.

[Screen shot link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE3Aq.png)