# Horrendous performance & large heap footprint of Java 8 constructor reference?

Tags: java, constructor, java-8, out-of-memory, method-reference

I just had a rather unpleasant experience in our production environment, causing `OutOfMemoryErrors: heapspace..`

I traced the issue to my use of `ArrayList::new` in a function.

To verify that this is actually performing worse than normal creation via a declared constructor (`t -> new ArrayList<>()`), I wrote the following small method:

```
public class TestMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean newMethod = false;
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int index = 0;

    while(true){
      if (newMethod) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(index, ArrayList::new).add(index);
     } else {
        map.computeIfAbsent(index, i->new ArrayList<>()).add(index);
      }
      if (index++ % 100 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Reached index "+index);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running the method with `newMethod=true;` will cause the method to fail with `OutOfMemoryError` just after index hits 30k. With `newMethod=false;` the program does not fail, but keeps pounding away until killed (index easily reaches 1.5 milion).

Why does `ArrayList::new` create so many `Object[]` elements on the heap that it causes `OutOfMemoryError` so fast?

(By the way - it also happens when the collection type is `HashSet`.)

Comment: A subtle one. +1 for something that one can easily stumble over...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In the first case (`ArrayList::new`) you are using the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) which takes an initial capacity argument, in the second case you are not. A large initial capacity (`index` in your code) causes a large `Object[]` to be allocated, resulting in your `OutOfMemoryError`s.

Here are the two constructors' current implementations:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    }
}
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Something similar happens in `HashSet`, except the array is not allocated until `add` is called.

Comment: @Durandal: The `Map.computeIfAbsent` method sends the value of the `index` variable to the constructor in the first case, creating a large bakcing array. In the second case the zero-argument constructor is used, which does not create a backing array at all.

Comment: Ah, so the index becomes actually the initial size. Thats clears things up, thanks.

Comment: @resueman: no, the default constructor of the Java 8 version doesn’t create a backing array until the first element will be added. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34250231/2711488

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it simply had not occurred to me that it would take the argument from the method in the Function and extrapolate that since it is an integer, it should might as well be used as argument in the constructor. I thought that using constructor reference would always take the empty constructor.
Thanks for the education!

Answer (score 81):

The `computeIfAbsent` signature is the following:

```
V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction)
```

So the `mappingFunction` is the function which *receives* one argument. In your case `K = Integer` and `V = List<Integer>`, so the signature becomes (omitting PECS):

```
Function<Integer, List<Integer>> mappingFunction
```

When you write `ArrayList::new` in the place where `Function<Integer, List<Integer>>` is necessary, compiler looks for the suitable constructor which is:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

So essentially your code is equivalent to

```
map.computeIfAbsent(index, i->new ArrayList<>(i)).add(index);
```

And your keys are treated as `initialCapacity` values which leads to pre-allocation of arrays of ever increasing size, which, of course, quite fast leads to `OutOfMemoryError`.

In this particular case constructor references are not suitable. Use lambdas instead. Were the `Supplier<? extends V>` used in `computeIfAbsent`, then `ArrayList::new` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer - think alex came first though, so he gets credit for the solution :)

Comment: @AndersK, no problems. I just wanted to explain the same with different words (probably for some people my answer is more clear).

Comment: Ha! Now I know where the microsoft "genuses" are getting they're MVC syntax.