# Writing a lambda expression when parameters are ignored in the body

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How do I write a lambda expression if it doesn't require arguments and hence its name is excessive?

This way doesn't compile:

```
setRowFactory(-> new TableRowCustom());
```

But this one does:

```
setRowFactory(__ -> new TableRowCustom());
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the functional interface type (and method) expected by `setRowFactory`'s parameter?

Comment: you can also use a method reference with just TableRowCustom::new which is a replacement for the lambda

Comment: @george, you can't use a method reference to reference a method that does not take the same number of parameters as the target functional type (here 0 vs 1, apparently).

Comment: @Didier L based on the Dims example he's got a default constructor and a supplier lambda interface so in his example what I've suggested will 100% work. You refer to cases when the constructor has parameters etc. but that's a different story than the question above.

Comment: @george His constructor has no parameters, and the expected interface obviously takes one (as he says that it compiles with `__`), so it cannot be a simple `Supplier`. In fact I think it is likely a JavaFX `Callback` by googling the method name, cf [TableView#setRowFactory(Callback)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setRowFactory-javafx.util.Callback-).

Comment: it doesn't really matter whether there are params or not, as long as the lambda interface finds a relevant constructor which satisfies the target type it will still work flawlessly with TableRowCustom::new at compile time. Based on your example with Callable it will look like Callable<TableRowCustom> newOp = TableRowCustom::new;

Comment: @george the method reference will look for a constructor with 1 parameter, of a super type of TableView, so it won't work

Comment: @Didier L the OP can always define a method called say createNewTB which accepts some parameter and returns a new TableRowCustom with no parameters. Then he only have to call TableRowCustom::createNewTB for the lambda

Comment: @george: just using constructor references without thinking about unintended functional parameters can lead to scenarios like in [“Horrendous performance & large heap footprint of Java 8 constructor reference”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35296734/2711488)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that this works

```
setRowFactory(__ -> new TableRowCustom());
```

I assume that the expected functional interface method must accept a single argument. [The identifier `_` is a reserved keyword since Java 8.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523946/underscore-is-a-reserved-keyword)

I would just use a throwaway single (valid identifier) character.

```
setRowFactory(i -> new TableRowCustom());
setRowFactory($ -> new TableRowCustom());
```

Although, you should probably avoid the use of the `$`, the Java Language Specification [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

> The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems. The underscore may be used in identifiers formed of two or more characters, but it cannot be used as a one-character identifier due to being a keyword.

You can also write out

```
setRowFactory(ignored -> new TableRowCustom());
```

to be explicit.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1) defines the syntax of a lambda expression

```
LambdaExpression:
  LambdaParameters -> LambdaBody
```

and

```
LambdaParameters:
  Identifier
  ( [FormalParameterList] )
  ( InferredFormalParameterList )
InferredFormalParameterList:
  Identifier {, Identifier}
```

In other words, you cannot omit an identifier.

---

As [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597728/java-8-writing-a-lambda-expression-when-arguments-arent-needed/37597939?noredirect=1#comment62681143_37597939) suggests, if and when they decide to use `_` as an unused parameter name, it will be easy to change from `__` to `_` in your source code. You may want to just stick with that for now.

Comment: I wouldn’t object using `__` for an unnecessary parameter as apparently the single `_` is reserved because it is intended to become the throwaway identifier for unused parameters in the future. When this happened, changing `__ -> expression` to `_ -> expression` wouldn’t be a big deal.

Comment: Unfortunately __ doesn't work in the same way python placeholders work, because `(__,__,whatIcareAbout)` causes 
  `java: variable __ is already defined in method` Error. ignored1, ignored2 may be preferable

Comment: Use `(__,___,whatIcareAbout)` then... Not optimal for now, but it's clearly showing the purpose.

Comment: Why "avoid this" for using dollar sign ? i know it is a special identifier meant for generated code, but is there some special case it represents or reasons why it should be avoided other than simple nomenclature ?

Comment: @niken No that's pretty much it, I've added a note from the JLS to clarify the comment.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 21 (September 2023), you can do:

```java
setRowFactory(_ -> new TableRowCustom());
```

`_` is the so-called "unnamed variable" ([preview feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12)). From [JEP 443](https://openjdk.org/jeps/443):

> Enhance the Java language with *unnamed patterns*, which match a record component without stating the component's name or type, and *unnamed variables*, which can be initialized but not used. Both are denoted by an underscore character, `_`. This is a [preview language feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12).
>
> […]
>
> An *unnamed variable* is declared when either the local variable in a local variable declaration statement, or an exception parameter in a catch clause, or a lambda parameter in a lambda expression is denoted by an underscore. It allows the identifier which follows the type or var in the statement or expression to be elided; e.g.,
>
> - `int _ = q.remove();`
> - `... } catch (NumberFormatException _) { ...`
> - `(int x, int _) -> x + x`
>
> In the case of single-parameter lambda expressions, such as `_ -> "NODATA"`, the unnamed variable should not be confused with the unnamed pattern.

The terminology indeed is a bit confusing, but [Nicolai Parlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP1k412Bylw) comes to rescue:

> *Unnamed variables* work as:
>
> - local variable
> - try-with-resource
> - for loop variable
> - exception parameter
> - lambda parameter
>
> They work with `var`.
>
> *Unnamed pattern variables*:
>
> - work as pattern variables
> - require explicit type
>
> *Unnamed patterns*:
>
> - replace pattern with `_`
> - bind nothing
> - match everything
> - only in nested patterns