# Java set collection clarification

Tags: java, collections

I was thinking of creating a list with keys and values in java and decided to create something like

```
private static HashMap<String, Set<String>> battleTanks = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

then i was trying to add a few values there like battleTanks.put("keytest1", "valuetest1")

But it's giving me an error like

> The method put(String, Set) in the type HashMap> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

so how can i add those values?

Comment: Given then value is a `Set<String>`, why would `put` with a value as a `String` work? Think it through - this will be a valuable lesson. Hint: you need [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: you are passing string as the value but its expecting a `set` that is why you are facing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to be doing is adding a `Set` as the value of your `Map`.

The `computeIfAbsent` method is a clean way of doing this, as it will either get the set that's already in the map for your key, or create a new one if it's not already there:

```
battleTanks.computeIfAbsent("keytest1", k -> new HashSet<>()).add("valuetest1")
```

Comment: I like to use `__` for uneeded parameters. It's a bit of a [cludge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37597939/2071828) but makes the intent clear.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't like because that's against the Java way. If it was the Java way, they would never have deprecated `_` (only 1 underscore).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire see Holger's comment on my link - the whole _reason_ that `_` was disallowed was so that it could become a throwaway later. In either case, Holger's opinion holds a lot of weight on the "Java way". I shortly, I strong disgree with your assertion about the "Java way", whatever that might be.