# Java Map computeIfAbsent issue

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

So I found a curiosity with Java's Map `computeIfAbsent` (using java8) method and I hope someone can tell me why this is happening as I can not really follow the logic behind that issue.

So, I have a Map with a key (obviously) and the value is a list and I use the computeIfAbsent to create a new list when a key is not set yet. Now when I use an Integer as key I can use the following:

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent(1, ArrayList::new);
```

But when I use a String as key trying to use

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent("key", ArrayList::new);
```

I get the error that `The method computeIfAbsent(String, Function<? super String,? extends List<Object>>) in the type Map<String,List<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList::new)`. Is there just the implementation missing? Using a String key I have to use the method like that, which is then working again.

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new ArrayList<>());
```

Maybe someone can enlighten me about that. Thanks :)

Comment: As a side note, Guava's `MultiMap` already implements what you're looking for.

Comment: and its worth mentioning the type of `map` used in the code for clarity of the question

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but it's hard to find :-/

Comment: Ah, there it is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35296734/3182664 - any objections to close this one as a duplicate of the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The mapping function - `Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction` - maps a key to a value, so when the key is `Integer`, `ArrayList::new` works, since `ArrayList` has a constructor that takes an int (the initial capacity). On the other hand, it doesn't have a constructor that takes a `String`.

Since the key probably shouldn't affect the initial capacity of the `ArrayList`, you should not use a method reference here (in both cases). Use lambda expression.

To make it clearer:

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent(1, ArrayList::new);
```

behaves similar to:

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> new ArrayList<>(k));
```

so it will create an `ArrayList` with initial capacity of 1.

On the other hand:

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent("key", ArrayList::new);
```

behaves similar to:

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new ArrayList<>(k));
```

where `k` is a `String`, so it doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: And more specifically, `1 -> ArrayList::new` does not in fact produce a list with the value `1` inserted.

Comment: So when using `ArrayList::new` the given key is inserted into the list? That in my example I'd have a List with the value 1 already in it?

Comment: @chrylis did the OP expect such behavior (1 being inserted into the List)? I didn't see that mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Fussel no, chrylis's comment said it "does not" insert 1 into the list.

Comment: Ah, I see but as I don't want the key being part of the list I'll use the lambda expression. If the generated list is `List<String>` it does also work the a string as key.

Comment: @Fussel the key will **not** be part of the list either way, but you are correct to use lambda expressions in both cases (Integer and String key). No, the `List` being `List<String>` makes no difference, since the key is not added to the List, it is passed to the `ArrayList` constructor (which doesn't work for Strings, since ArrayList has no constructor that accepts a String).

Comment: @Fussel If you replace `1` with 1 billion you might get a memory error since Java will try to allocate an array that has the capacity of storing 1 billion elements. Note that capacity != actual elements. An empty `ArrayList` can consume an arbitrary amount of memory depending on the capacity.

Answer (score 9):

Your second attempt

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent("key", ArrayList::new);
```

would actually be equal to

```
List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new ArrayList<>(k));
```

and since `ArrayList` has no constructor taking a String as a parameter, it doesn't work. The first example works as it creates a list with one element.