# Strange lambda behaviour in Java stream

Tags: java, lambda, stream, hashmap, java-stream

I created the following method that adds the given UUID value with the given Integer to teh `map` variable.

```
final Map<Integer, List<UUID>> map = new TreeMap<>();

private void addToMap(Integer key, UUID value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, val -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

Normally I was tried to use `map.computeIfAbsent(key, value -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);` by passing `value` parameter to the lambda function, it it throws "*Variable 'value' is already defined in the scope*" error pointing the "value" in `.. value ->  ...` part.

My updated `addToMap` method is working, but I think `val` is pointless. So, how should this method be updated?

Comment: I don't think you can do much more than you've already done. Other languages use `_` for this purpose but that's a reserved keyword since Java 9

Comment: Thanks a lot. After asking the question, I have seen that there is a similar usage in `computeIfAbsent` method explanations. So, val is only used at that place. So, I can use it like I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addToMap()` method implies a wrong understanding of the parameters of the `computeIfAbsent()` method:

```
private void addToMap(Integer key, UUID value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, val -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

The parameter in `val -> new ArrayList<>()` has nothing to do with the `value` that you pass into `addToMap()`!

If you look at the JavaDoc for [Map.computeIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) you can see that the second parameter is a `Function<? super K,​? extends V>` - i.e. a function that takes a key and returns whatever should be stored in the map.

It would be better to write the `addToMap()` method as

```
private void addToMap(Integer key, UUID value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

Note that the answer from toniedzwiedz is dangerous. It only works for a `Map<Integer, ?>` with keys greater than or equal to zero.

It is dangerous because it basically replaces `k -> new ArrayList<>()` with `k -> new ArrayList<>(k)` - this happens to work for maps with `Integer` keys and uses the key value to define the initial capacity of the `ArrayList`.

It will not work if `k` is negative (`new ArrayList<>(k)` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if k is negative).

It will also not work for a `Map<String, UUID>` because there is no `ArrayList` constructor that takes a `String` argument.

Comment: Using `ArrayList::new` is not only dangerous because it can fail with an exception when the key is negative, it may also appear to run with no immediately recognizable issue but a horrendous performance, [until you realize something’s wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35296734/2711488)…