# Why does using different ArrayList constructors cause a different growth rate of the internal array?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-12

I seem to stumble across something interesting in `ArrayList` implementation that I can't wrap my head around. Here is some code that shows what I mean:

```
public class Sandbox {

    private static final VarHandle VAR_HANDLE_ARRAY_LIST;

    static {
        try {
            Lookup lookupArrayList = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(ArrayList.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
            VAR_HANDLE_ARRAY_LIST = lookupArrayList.findVarHandle(ArrayList.class, "elementData", Object[].class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> defaultConstructorList = new ArrayList<>();
        defaultConstructorList.add("one");

        Object[] elementData = (Object[]) VAR_HANDLE_ARRAY_LIST.get(defaultConstructorList);
        System.out.println(elementData.length);

        List<String> zeroConstructorList = new ArrayList<>(0);
        zeroConstructorList.add("one");

        elementData = (Object[]) VAR_HANDLE_ARRAY_LIST.get(zeroConstructorList);
        System.out.println(elementData.length);

    }
}
```

The idea is if you create an `ArrayList` like this:

```
List<String> defaultConstructorList = new ArrayList<>();
defaultConstructorList.add("one");
```

And look inside what the `elementData` (`Object[]` where all elements are kept) the it will report `10`. Thus you add one element - you get 9 additional slots that are un-used.

If, on the other hand, you do:

```
List<String> zeroConstructorList = new ArrayList<>(0);
zeroConstructorList.add("one");
```

you add one element, *space reserved is just for that element*, nothing more.

Internally this is achieved via two fields:

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for empty instances.
 */
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};

/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for default sized empty instances. We
 * distinguish this from EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA to know how much to inflate when
 * first element is added.
 */
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

---

When you create an `ArrayList` via `new ArrayList(0)` - `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` will be used.

When you create an `ArrayList` via `new Arraylist()` - `DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` is used.

The intuitive part from inside me - simply screams "remove `DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA`" and let all the cases be handled with `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA`; of course the code comment:

> We distinguish this from EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA to know how much to inflate when first element is added

does make sense, but why would one inflate to `10` (a lot more than I asked for) and the other one to `1` (exactly as much as I requested).

---

Even if you use `List<String> zeroConstructorList = new ArrayList<>(0)`, and keep adding elements, eventually you will get to a point where `elementData` is bigger than the one requested:

```
    List<String> zeroConstructorList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    zeroConstructorList.add("one");
    zeroConstructorList.add("two");
    zeroConstructorList.add("three");
    zeroConstructorList.add("four");
    zeroConstructorList.add("five"); // elementData will report 6, though there are 5 elements only
```

But the rate at which it grows is smaller than the case of default constructor.

---

This reminds me about `HashMap` implementation, where the number of buckets is almost always more than you asked for; but there that is done because of the need for "power of two" buckets needed, not the case here though.

So the question is - can someone explain this difference to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java 8, why is the default capacity of ArrayList now zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250207/in-java-8-why-is-the-default-capacity-of-arraylist-now-zero)

Comment: @Joe I have seen and read that one, but it address a different question - that explains the fact that an empty `ArrayList` will _not_ have an array of size `10` anymore; the array is computed lazily - this is entirely different

Comment: @Eugene It's not really completely different. Notice that now we have *two* different strategies implemented in `ArrayList` where there used to be only one. To decide which strategy to use, the new constant was introduced.

Comment: @JimmyB exactly the question - _why_ are there two of them now? the idea in that Q&A is that `ArrayList` now, when it has no entries, will be backed up by an empty array, which can be achieved via `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA`, so why keep both?

Comment: @Eugene I have nothing concrete to back this up, but I would imagine that it would cause hard-to-identify issues in existing code that allocated a lot of default-ctor instances, and kept adding (up to) 10 elements to them. If it grew like the `new ArrayList<>(0)` case, you'd end up allocating more backing arrays, and this might increase memory usage/GC usage.

Comment: @AndyTurner actually I specifically did not hinted towards this myself, I can only assume that while analyzing lots of live applications; they came to the conclusion that the vast majority of `new ArrayList()` : 1) either don't add anything to it (thus the need for an empty array) 2) add up to 10 elements, but closer to 10 all the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get precisely what you asked for, respective what has been specified, even in older versions, where the implementation was different:

[`ArrayList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--)

> Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

[`ArrayList(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-)

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

So, constructing the `ArrayList` with the default constructor will give you an `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of ten, so as long as the list size is ten or smaller, no resize operation will ever be needed.

In contrast, the constructor with the `int` argument will precisely use the specified capacity, subject to the [growing policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is specified as

> The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

which applies even when you specify an initial capacity of zero.

Java 8 added the optimization that the creation of the ten elements array is postponed until the first element is added. This is specifically addressing the common case that `ArrayList` instances (created with the default capacity) stay empty for a long time or even their entire lifetime. Further, when the first actual operation is `addAll`, it might skip the first array resize operation. This does not affect lists with an explicit initial capacity, as those are usually chosen carefully.

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250231/2711488):

> According to our performance analysis team, approximately 85% of ArrayList instances are created at default size so this optimization will be valid for an overwhelming majority of cases.

The motivation was to optimize precisely these scenarios, not to touch the specified default capacity, which was defined back when `ArrayList` was created. (Though [JDK 1.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20031204164228/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.1/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList()) is the first one specifying it explicitly)

Comment: I'd consider rewording parts of the answer, since the *initial capacity* is in fact no longer 10 (except for an inappropriately gracious interpretation of what the "initial capacity" should mean...).

Comment: @Marco13 the answer uses the same wording as [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-). The initial capacity is ten; there’s just an optimization adding laziness to the first array creation. Anything else is unaffected, especially any consideration regarding whether and what to specify as alternative initial capacity when using `ArrayList`, does not change.

Comment: Again, this may be considered as a nitpick about the term "initial capacity": It is, so to say, vague enough so that they could change the behavior in Java 8. But before that, "initial capacity" meant: The size of the internal array directly after construction. And this was 10. Now it is 0. Or to put it that way: If you call 10 the "initial capacity", how to you call the 0? The "pre-initial capacity"?

Comment: @Marco13 since that zero-sized array is not specific to the `ArrayList` instance, but a shared array, merely a marker that the initial size is the default one, I wouldn’t call its size “initial capacity”. They could have used `null` instead, but decided to use the marker array due to known interactions with the JVM’s optimizer. Besides that, I still think, that the behavior is easily understandable when describing it in terms of “initial capacity”, be it the way you expect, and then adding the fact that there is a specific optimization for a specific case, diverging from that meaning.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the default constructor, the idea is to try to balance memory usage and reallocation. Hence a small default size (10) is used that should be fine for most applications.

If you use the constructor with an explicit size, it is assumed that you know what you're doing. If you initialize it with 0 you are essentially saying: I am pretty sure this will either stay empty or not grow beyond very few elements.

Now if you look at the implementations of `ensureCapacityInternal` in openjdk ([link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)), you can see that only the first time you add an item, this difference comes into play:

```
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    if (elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
    }

    ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
}
```

If the default constructor is used, the size grows to `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` (10). This is to prevent too many reallocations if multiple elements are added. However if you explicitly created this ArrayList with size 0, it will simply grow to size 1 on the first element you add. This is because you told it that you know what you're doing.

`ensureExplicitCapacity` basically just calls `grow` (with some range/overflow checks), so let's look at that:

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't simply grow to a specific size, but it tries to be smart. The bigger the array is, the bigger it will grow even if `minCapacity` is just 1 bigger than the current capacity. The reasoning behind that is simple: The probability that a lof of items will be added is higher if the list is already big and vice versa. This is also why you see growth increments by 1 and then by 2 after the 5th element.

Comment: I might have to think about it a bit more, but I like your reasonings; especially the ones on the very bottom of your answer.

Comment: The non-linear growth is even mandatory, to provide the guaranty “that adding an element has constant amortized time cost”, as when you grow the array by one on each `add`, you’d end up at quadratic time costs for all added elements.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is what is in the Java doc: We have *two* constants because we now need to be able to distinguish the *two* different initializations later, see below.

Instead of two constants they could of course have introduced e.g. a boolean field in `ArrayList`, `private boolean initializedWithDefaultCapacity`; but that would require additional memory *per instance*, which seems to be against the goal to *save* a few bytes of memory.

Why do we need to distinguish those two?

Looking at `ensureCapacity()` we see what happens with `DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA`:

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    int minExpand = (elementData != DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA)
        // any size if not default element table
        ? 0
        // larger than default for default empty table. It's already
        // supposed to be at default size.
        : DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

    if (minCapacity > minExpand) {
        ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
    }
}
```

It seems that it is done this way to be somewhat 'compatible' to the behavior of the old implementation:

If you did initialize the list with the default capacity, it will actually be initialized with an empty array now, *but*, as soon as the first element is inserted, it will basically revert to the same behavior as the old implementation, i.e. after the first element is added, the backing array has the `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` and from then on, the list behaves the same as previously.

If, on the other hand, you explicitly specifiy an inital capacity, the array does not 'jump' to `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` but grows relatively from your specified initial capacity.

I figure the reason for this 'optimization' may be for cases where you know you will be only storing one or two (i.e. less than `DEFAULT_CAPACITY`) elements in the list and you specify the initial capacity accordingly; in these cases, for example for a single-element list, you only get a single-element array, instead of a `DEFAULT_CAPACITY`-sized.

Don't ask me what the *practical* benefit is of saving nine array elements of a reference type. Might be up to about 9*64 bit = 72 bytes of RAM per list. Yeay. ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your "trial" of an answer, but its only stating the same question from a different angle... and a reference is probably more like `32` bits; unless you have a pretty darn big heap.

Comment: I don't think it repeats the question. The short answer to your question is what is in the Java doc: We have *two* constants because we now need to be able to distinguish the *two* different initializations later, i.e. in `ensureCapacity()`. Why do we need to distinguish those two? - Because we want to be compatible in one case and optimize for memory in the other case, see `ensureCapacity()`.

Comment: @Eugene Instead of two constants, they could of course have introduced e.g. a boolean field in `ArrayList`, `private boolean initializedWithDefaultCap;` but that would require additional memory per instance, which seems to be against the goal to *save* memory.

Comment: I guess that on 64-bit JVMs object references internally will be of the native pointer size, i.e. 64 bits. Besides, it the JVM does *support* more than 2GB of heap it *must* use pointers > 32 bits.

Comment: @Eugene Oh, didn't now that flag. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the case that the two constructor have different perceived default uses.

The default (empty) constructor assumes that this will be a "typical `ArrayList`". Therefore, the number `10` is chosen as a sort of heuristic, aka "what the typical average number of elements inserted will be that will not take up too much space but will not grow the array needlessly too". On the other hand, the capacity constructor has the presupposition of "you know what you're doing" or "you know what you will be using the `ArrayList for`". Therefore, no heuristics of this type are present.

Answer (score 0):

The capacity with the default constructor is 10 simply because [the docs say so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--). It would have been chosen as a sensible compromise between not using up too much memory off the bat, and not having to perform lots of array copies when adding the first few elements.

The zero behaviour is slightly speculative, but I'm fairly confident with my reasoning here:

It's because if you *explicitly* initialise an `ArrayList` with a size of zero, then add something to it, you're saying "I'm not expecting this list to hold much, if anything at all." It therefore makes much, much more sense to grow the backing array slowly, as though it was initialised with a value of 1, rather than treating it as if it had no initial value specified at all. So it handles the special case of growing it to just 1 element, and then carries on as normal.

To then complete the picture, an `ArrayList` explicitly initialised with a size of 1 would be expected to grow much more slowly (up to the point it hits the default "10 element" size) than the default one, otherwise there'd be no reason to initialise it with a small value in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> but why would one inflate to 10 (a lot more than I asked for) and the other one to 1 (exactly as much as I requested)

Probably because most people that create lists want to store **more than** 1 element in it.

You know, when you want exactly one entry, why not use `Collections.singletonList()` for example.

In other words, I think the answer is **pragmatism**. When you use the default constructor, the **typical** use case would be that you are going to add maybe a handful or so of elements quickly.

Meaning: "unknown" is interpreted as "a few", whereas "exactly 0 (or 1)" is interpreted "hmm, exactly 0 or 1".